# Difference between *.tex and *.txt Files

Tags: compiling, text-manipulation

Is there any difference between the two file-formats? Do I see all the data, when I open a `.tex` file using a Standard Text-Editor in Windows? Do `.tex` files have some kind of meta-data or disguised data I would not see?

My issue is like this. I have received a `.tex` file I would like to process. Would it be the same if I:

1. Process it directly
2. Open it using standard Windows Text-Editor, copy-paste the Content to a newly created `.tex` file (using e.g. TexnicCenter) and then process this resulting `.tex` file.

I would like to avoid any kind of malware or stuff like this. When I use the second approach I actually see the content since I copy-paste only the visible data.

Comment: A `.tex` file is just text.

Comment: Barring any differences in file encodings (UTF-8 or others), yes, the result would be the same.

Comment: tex files are plain text (and can have any extension or no extension at all)

Comment: I suspect two problems when copy-paste of simple text from one application to another is completed. First: long lines can be broken. Second: encoding can be changed because of some unwanted intelligence of used applications. Both types of changes can cause different processing in TeX. Maybe, copy-paste can do 1:1 but it cannot. It depens on operating system and on used applications.

Comment: For what it's worth, opening _any_ file in a text editor will _always_ show you all the content of the file. For some files (like `.exe` files) part of that content will be invisible/unprintable characters, and the rest will look like gibberish, but the point is, a text editor will attempt to faithfully display every single byte in the file. Text editors don't have any concept of macros or formatting commands or any other sort of hidden data.

Comment: @DavidZ this is not true, there are many text editors (at least in windows) that stop reading text files at the first EOF. This is caused by the underlying Windows file API. A text editor will normally tell the api it wants to read a text (non-binary) file (a differentiation unknown in Unix), and then the file api will only read the file up to the first EOF.

Comment: @Alexander hm, I didn't know that. (What value represents EOF?) Though I still think it's a useful point to make that a text editor will either display or discard the entire contents of the file, so there's no possibility to transmit malware in a text file as the OP seems to be worried about (except by exploiting a major bug in the text editor).

Answer (score 16):

File extensions are mainly a naming convention. Source code in almost all programming languages is plain text, and there is no technical difference between a file named `.txt` or `.tex` or `.asdasdasd` or whatever.

Comment: how about `filename.exe`?

Comment: @Ohmyghost In terms of file content it makes no odds :-) Note for example that `.com` is used by some programs to mean something very different from the classic DOS executable of the same extension.

Comment: @Ohmyghost TeX would be quite happy with that file name (whether a windows editor opens it by default is a different question)

Comment: @JosephWright and \ampersand David: OK Thanks.

Comment: @Ohmyghost .exe in windows generally tells the operating system, that the file is executable and therefore has the right format to be put into the processor. Other file extensions are registered to be opened with certain editors like notepad or Word or whatever. But because of the stupidity of notepad you can be shure that there is no meta information in a file when you can open it in notepad without any problems and there are no awkward symbols.

Comment: @Ohmyghost `.exe` means 'executable' and it denotes a binary (not human-readable, but machine-readable) file. You can rename it to `.asdasdasd` if you want, but then you can't run it.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in the comments, `.tex` files are just plain-text files, so they do not have "hidden metadata".

If you inspect it with any text editor as Notepad, TeXnicCenter etc... you will see the contents byte per byte (encoding issues apart, which are off-topic it would seem).

If your concern is how safe it is to run `latex` (or variants) on the file, the answer is simple. It is pretty safe, the worst it can do is be stuck in a loop and produce some garbage in the form of easy-to-delete temporary `.aux` files.
Things change if you compile it using the `-shell-escape` argument: this would allow the `.tex` file to execute external programs and this could be potentially harmful. You can explicitly disable this behaviour by running the `latex` command with the `-no-shell-escape` argument.

There are packages that make legitimate use of this feature (`minted` comes to mind). To be sure nothing nasty is going to happen you need to inspect the contents of the `.tex` file.

But: **Absolutely no harm can be caused by inspecting the file with a text editor.**

As mentioned before, even plain-text files can be harmful in Windows if assigned extensions that instruct the operating system to interpret them as programs (examples are `.bat` files or `.vbs`). To avoid this you can open the file from your text editor's menu: this way you avoid Windows guessing how to open the file.

Comment: By default restricted shell escape is enabled. So some external programmes can be run within certain constraints. I think, but am not sure, that `-no-shell-escape` is more restrictive. This all goes for TeX Live. I've no idea about MiKTeX.

Answer (score 6):

To expand a bit on the other answers, a `.tex`file is the same file format as `.txt` from the operating system's perspective. Both are plain text files.

A plain text file contains nothing but series of character-codes, which a text editor tells the computer to display as letters according to the codes. There are different encodings, with UTF-8 being now used almost universally. There is no invisible data or metadata (except the filename itself, the timestamp, etc., which are specific to the operating system).

You can take a `.txt` file and change the suffix to `.tex`, or vice versa, and *nothing changes* except the filename. It is just a convention to name the files this way. If given a filename without an extension, the TeX engines will look for a `.tex`; but otherwise it doesn't matter.

You can create the .tex file in any editor, not just a special TeX program. On a Unix-like system, you can even create one from the command line.

Comment: RE: The last sentence: Windows can do it too! :-)